# C++ std::transform vector of pairs->first to new vector

Tags: c++, vector, transform, functor, std-pair

Sorry for a little bit beginner question. There are vector and vector of pairs

```
typedef std::vector <int> TItems;
typedef std::vector < std::pair <int, int> > TPairs;
```

Is there any way to transform all first items in pair to another vector in one step

```
int main ()
{
TItems items;
TPairs pairs;

pairs.push_back (std::make_pair(1,3));
pairs.push_back (std::make_pair(5,7));

std::transform( items.begin(), items.end(), items.begin(), comp ( &pairs ) );

return 0;
}
```

How to design a functor?

```
class comp
{
private:
     TPairs *pairs;

public:
    comp ( TPairs  *pairs_ ) : pairs ( pairs_) { }

    unsigned int operator () ( const unsigned int index ) const
    {
        return  (*pairs)[index].second != pairs->end();  //Bad idea
    }
};
```

Maybe there is some more user friendly method without lambda expressions and loops. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, you should use a [`back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/) as the third argument to [`transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) so that the transformed values are pushed to the back of the vector.

Second, you need some sort of functor which takes a pair of ints and returns the first one. This should do:

```
int firstElement( const std::pair<int, int> &p ) {
    return p.first;
}
```

Now, to put the pieces together:

```
TPairs pairs;
pairs.push_back( std::make_pair( 1, 3 ) );
pairs.push_back( std::make_pair( 5, 7 ) );

TItems items;
std::transform( pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter( items ),
                firstElement );
```

After this code, `items` contains 1 and 5.

Comment: Is there any clever way to use [std::get<0>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) instead of your custom function?

Answer (score 19):

see frerich's or kotlinski's answer for C++03.

C++11 solution with lambda:

```
std::transform(pairs.begin(), 
               pairs.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(items), 
               [](const std::pair<int, int>& p) { return p.first; });
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the "no lambda's" requirement, but why when it is straightforward and part of the language?

Comment: I believe it's not part of the C++ language which most of the people around here can actually use (either due to compiler limitations or because of some requirements by the work place).

Answer (score 12):

I really want you to use `std::get` as the functor, because it's already provided as a library function!!

Wouldn't it be great if we could write this line!?

```
std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter(items), std::get<0>);
```

... But it's a bit more terrible than that. You need to disambiguate which `get` to use:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> items;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;

  pairs.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 3));
  pairs.push_back(std::make_pair(5, 7));

  std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter(items),
                 (const int& (*)(const std::pair<int, int>&))std::get<0>);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, `std::get` [is overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get) to take 1. `pair&`, 2. `const pair&`, and 3. `pair&&` as the parameters, so that it will work for any sort of pair as input. Unfortunately, the overloads get in the way of the template type deduction for `std::transform`, so our original line

```
std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter(items), std::get<0>);
```

yields

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter(items), std::get<0>);
                                                                                    ^
...

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4915:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_UnaryOperation’
   std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::back_inserter(items), std::get<0>);
```

It doesn't know which overload of `std::get` you are asking for when deducing the template for `std::transform`, so you have to specify it manually. Casting the function pointer to the right type tells the compiler, "Hey, please use the overload where `get` takes a `const&` and returns a `const&`!"

But at least we're using standard library components (yay)?

And in terms of number of lines, it's no worse than the other options:
http://ideone.com/6dfzxz

Comment: Can anyone think of any improvements? It'd be great to be able to cleanly use `std::get` like this.

...Really I should probably be using `reinterperet_cast<const int& (*)(const std::pair<int, int>&)>(std::get<0>)`, but that seems even worse...

Comment: I think it is possible to replace the "hard" cast with the get function wrapped inside a lambda for which one can specify the arguments

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
items.reserve(pairs.size());
for (size_t it = 0; it < pairs.size(); ++it) {
    items.push_back(pairs[it].first);
}
```

Simple to understand and debug.

Comment: @ kotlinski: Thanks, but this is a common solution. I would like to find one-step solution without any loop, if possible.

Comment: You asked for something user friendly, then it would be misleading to post an answer with some C++ atrocity :)

Comment: +1: simplest in this case.  Why avoid loops if they simplify?

Comment: @stefaanv: Because the OP explicitely asked for an answer `without lambda expressions and loops.`.

Comment: @Frerich: my why was actually referring to that limitation, but I admit that that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Frerich, don't get me wrong, I like your answer for staying closest to the original querstion, so I referenced it in my answer, but this one takes a little step back and says "hold on, it can be simpler" (I would still use iterators)

Comment: OP did not actually ask for loop-free solution.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `std::bind`?

```
std::transform(pairs.begin(), 
               pairs.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(items), 
               std::bind(&TPairs::value_type::first, std::placeholders::_1));
```

(Replace `std::bind` by `boost::bind` for non-C++11 code)

Answer (score 3):

another possibility from C++11 would be [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), which is similar to solution with `std::bind`:

```
std::transform(pairs.begin(), 
               pairs.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(items), 
               std::mem_fn(&std::pair<int,int>::first)               
);
```