# Create a vector of int from a vector of points with C++11

Tags: c++, vector, c++11

I have a simple point structure

```
struct mypoint
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and a `vector` of `mypoint`s

```
vector<mypoint> myvector;
```

If I want to create a vector of `int` containing all the coordinates of my points (i.e. `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `x3`, `y3`, ...), I could easily do it in the following way

```
vector<mypoint>::iterator pt, ptend(myvector.end());
vector<int> newvector;

for(pt=myvector.begin(); pt!=ptend; ++pt)
{
    newvector.push_back(pt->x);
    newvector.push_back(pt->y);
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result in one (or two) line(s) of code using the C++11?

Comment: "Make it a function" is not applicable?  Your code is very readable as it stands.  Do you want to sacrifice that?

Comment: you can make it prettier by using `auto pt = myvector.begin()`. For perfomance you may reserve or resize `newvector` and use `cbegin()` and `cend` in the loop.

Comment: @DrewDormann It was just to explore some new functions of the C++11 unknown to me. I agree that make the code unreadable is not a good idea.

Comment: Just as a side note: the data managed by `newvector` will probably end up being binary equal to the data managed by `myvector` (assuming the struct is densely packed). If you're just doing this conversion so you can pass your data to a C function expecting an `int*`, you might just get away with passing `myvector`s data, avoiding the copy completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> extractIntsFromPoints(const std::vector<mypoint>& pointVector)
{
    std::vector<int> retVector;    
    for (const auto& element : pointVector)
    {
        retVector.push_back(element.x);
        retVector.push_back(element.y);
    }
    return retVector;
}
```

Call this function where you need the int vector.
I threw in the range-based for loop to make it extra C++11.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using C++11, you can use the new for syntax.

```
vector<int> newvector;

for( const auto &pt : myvector)
{
    newvector.push_back(pt.x);
    newvector.push_back(pt.y);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, so I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: `pt->x` and `pt->y` should be `pt.x` and `pt.y` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

steal from the post: [C++ std::transform vector of pairs->first to new vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094132/c-stdtransform-vector-of-pairs-first-to-new-vector)

```
vector<int> items;
std::transform(pairs.begin(), 
               pairs.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(items), 
               [](const std::pair<int, int>& p) { return p.first; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's about 4 lines, using a lambda:

```
vector<mypoint> points;
vector<int> iv;

points.push_back(mypoint(1,2));
points.push_back(mypoint(3,4));
points.push_back(mypoint(5,6));

for_each(points.cbegin(), points.cend(),
    [&iv](const mypoint &pt) {
        iv.push_back(pt.x);
        iv.push_back(pt.y);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::pair<>` in which you push the coordinates using `std::make_pair` and then push the `std::pair<>` into the vector such as:

```
mypoint a_point;
std::pair<int, int> point = std::make_pair(a_point.x, a_point.y);
vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec.push_back(point).
```

Perhaps bulky but in two lines it works well and encapsulates a point rather than separating the magnitudes of each point axis and placing them inside a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

As reima already noted, if you only want to reference the existing sequence, it is sufficient to cast `myvector.data()` to `int*` (assuming `sizeof(mypoint) == 2 * sizeof(int)` holds).
However, if you explicitly want a copy of the flattened sequence, you are probably better off creating a small utility function like this:

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::vector<T> flatten(std::vector<U> const& other) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<U>::value,
                      "source type must be trivially copyable!");
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>::value,
                      "destination type must be trivially copy constructible!");
        static_assert((sizeof(U) / sizeof(T)) * sizeof(T) == sizeof(U),
                      "sizeof(U) must be a multiple of sizeof(T)!");

        return std::vector<T>(reinterpret_cast<T const*>(other.data()),
           reinterpret_cast<T const*>(std::next(other.data(), other.size())));             
    }

    template <typename U>
    std::vector<typename U::value_type> flatten(std::vector<U> const& other) {
         return flatten<typename U::value_type>(other);
    }
```

reducing your code to

```
    auto newvector = flatten<int>(myvector);
```

or - if you equip your `mypoint` `struct` with a (STL-conforming) `value_type` member type - even to

```
    auto newvector = flatten(myvector);
```

Note, that this utility function is nothing more than a tweaked constructor using the inherently unsafe `reinterpret_cast` to convert `mypoint` pointers into `int` pointers.
To get rid of the safety caveats that go along with the use of `reinterpret_cast`, the `flatten` function uses some `static_assert` parachutes. So, it's better to hide all this in a seprate function.
Still, it uses a lot of C++11 features like `auto`, move construction, `static_assert`, type traits, `std::next` and `vector::data()` which pretty much strips down your call site code to a bare minimum.

Also, this is as efficient as it gets because the range constructor of `vector` will only perform the memory allocation and call `uninitialized_copy`, which will probably boil down to a call of `memcpy` for trivially copyable types.