# Get vector of a specific member from a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a vector of structs as follows. The struct holds the relevant data for a plot.

```
struct DATA_T
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}

std::vector<DATA_T> results;
```

I need to be able to retrieve all the `x` values within results vector and store them as a vector of doubles

I know that I could create these vector programmatically.

```
std::vector<double> x_values;
x_values.reserve(results.size());
for(auto const &data : results)
{
    x_values.push_back(data.x);
}
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more concise solution. Perhaps using a similar approach to how I can search for specific data points using `find_if`?

Comment: you could use `std::transform`, but i doubt that it will be any faster or cleaner than what you already have, though you should reserve the right amount in the vector before calling `push_back`

Comment: Possibly duplicate with [C++ std::transform vector of pairs->first to new vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094132/c-stdtransform-vector-of-pairs-first-to-new-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for that providing it with appropriate lambda to retrieve `x`:

```
std::vector<double> x_values;
x_values.reserve(results.size());

std::transform(std::cbegin(results), std::cend(results),
    std::back_inserter(x_values),
    [](const auto& data) {
        return data.x;
    }
);
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fyNsuIZHSNgqptJz)

Comment: @iyop45 for this particular piece of code `std::transform` might be a good choice without loosing the readability. But in general case too many STL algorithms in a single place do no guarantee the readability at all :)